# Identifying unique browsers with a Spring backend and React frontend

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, rest

I am developing a web-based multiplayer boardgame, using a Spring/Java/Maven backend and React/JavaScript frontend. Since the game is turn-based, I want to identify each individual player so that I can ensure only the active player can click and I can send individual messages to each player.

We have been looking at using Spring Security, but we have been having issues with this. Identifying clients with users & passwords seems like overkill as we are not concerned about security, is there a better approach? Essentially, what is the best way to manage distinct users and then serve them with individual messages/actions?

Comment: Take the machine ip and create a user session once the user looged in. If the user again want to log in check if previous session is active.if so then decline it

Comment: session cookie?

Comment: @brk sure, in sudocode that makes sense, but what's the correct way to implement this in the given frameworks?

Comment: @epascarello session cookie is what I have seen other people discussing, but how does Spring implement this and send messages to individual sessions?

Comment: @saeched you want me to write the code for it? I think by now you have the idea, it will be much better for you if you pick each of the step and search how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it just in the same way that you'd do with VanillaJS i.e. gather as much information as possible from the visitor such as ip address, user agent etc.

Here is a list of available thing you can gather.
https://javascriptsource.com/browser-properties/

You might then base64 encode this information so that it creates a semi unique string. This could then be put in a database from which you'd query unique entrances.